# D3plus options having no effect on chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, d3plus

I originally posted this on the D3plus Google group but haven't recieved any response, so seeing if anyone here knows anything.

I've created a Treemap using D3plus and would like to edit the tooltip. I'd like to add a % suffix to one of the values and I'd like to remove the 'share' line altogether. I'd also like to change the global font size.

Here are the variables I've added...

```
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
.container("#viz")
.data(sample_data)
.type("tree_map")
.id("name")
.size("value")
.font( {"size":10 } )//to change font size
.color("growth")
.format({

  "number": function(number, key) {

    var formatted = d3plus.number.format(number, key)

    if (key === "growth") {
      return formatted + " %"
    }
    else {
      return formatted
    }

  }
}) // to add prefix
.draw()


});
```

They seem to have no effect whatsoever

Here is a link to my chart... http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/pensions2/index.html  Maybe I've made a mistake in the order I call the code or something but I'm really stuck,

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: Look at my plunkr...I am changing font size through css http://embed.plnkr.co/f3ofGRFItcrF7fA1va6f/preview

Answer (score 1):

Check the key variable, that d3plus passes to the function you provide for the number formatting. It's an object. To check against your "growth" key use key.key:

```
.format({

  "number": function(number, key) {

    var formatted = d3plus.number.format(number, key)

    if (key.key === "growth") {
      return formatted + " %"
    }
    else {
      return formatted
    }

  }
})
```

To remove the "share" line in the tooltip use the corresponding key:

```
.tooltip({
    "share": false
})
```

Unfortunately I could not change the font size - only changing the font family seems to work ...

```
.font({ "family": "Times" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the place of `.font( {"size":10 } )` you should put
`.font( {"size":10,"resize"=false } )` in your code because, By default it is true and u can't change the size if the resize is activated. 
I hope that could help